# ogr2ogr PQconnectdb connection error

Tags: postgis, gdal, postgresql, ogr2ogr, ubuntu

I am trying to convert a PostgreSQL table to CSV using `ogr2ogr`. Why is my command failing?

```
ogr2ogr -f CSV output.csv PG:"host=myhost port=5432 user='postgres' password='mypassword' dbname='mydb'" "myschema.mytable"
```

This is the error I get:

```
ERROR 1: PQconnectdb failed.
invalid connection option ""host"

FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `PG:"host=myhost' with the following drivers.
```

All of the drivers are listed, including PostgreSQL.

I have read that syntax and placement of quotations [are important](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28036259/1003708), but nothing I try seems to work.

I am trying to run this command in a Ubuntu Docker container. I installed `gdal` like this:

```
apt-get install gdal-bin
```

Version info:

```
# ogr2ogr --version
  GDAL 1.11.3, released 2015/09/16
```

I have verified that I can connect to the database using other similar method. For example, when I run `ogrinfo`, I connect and can see a full list of spatial tables, including the one from which I am trying to export.

Comment: The documented syntax http://www.gdal.org/drv_pg.html is like `PG:"dbname='databasename' host='addr' port='5432' user='x' password='y'"`. Try with single quotes around host and port.

Comment: @user30184 if I put dbname first I get "invalid connection option ""dbname". Single quotes on host and port gets same result.

Comment: Wild quess: Have you copy-pasted the command? In that case writing the command from keyboard may help. What looks like " is often something else in some fonts. And where is that `"myschema.mytable"`part documented? And `ogrinfo PG:"host=myhost port=5432 user='postgres' password='mypassword' dbname='mydb'"`works OK?

Comment: I am trying to bash script the ogr2ogr call. I believe the error is due to a silly error in my script. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have the same problem (running on debian unix) while executing the script using java  `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` - It always throws an error on the **first** parameter in the Postgres-connection string. No matter which is first. And no matter if the port and host is within single quotes or without.
It used to work (only) without the double quotes on debian unix machines until (?) and now it throws an error - but I am not sure if this is a Java Change

Comment: And If i copy this command to console it works, so it must have something to do with the double quotes and a change in some thing (java?)

Comment: This is closed, but here is an answer:  If running from the command line, you need the double quotes before host and after the database.  However, if running from subprocess inside python, and maybe also from a bash script, get rid of those double quotes.  This worked for me.